# A-frame hide vr mode symbol

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, aframe, webvr

I have created a scene using a-frame and I cant figure out how to hide the vr mode in the bottom right hand corner of the screen. I have tried the  `vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"` but for some reason it wasn't working. How can I hide the vr mode in my scene? Here is the link to my scene: https://jsfiddle.net/AidanYoung/k6johd1t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have assigned the `vr-mode-ui` parameter to the camera:

> `<a-camera limit-my-distance vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"></a-camera>`

You want to use it on the `a-scene` ([source](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/vr-mode-ui.html)) like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"></a-scene>
</body>

</html>
```